# What's the function of `Intent.setPackage()`

Tags: android, android-intent

What's the function of `Intent.setPackage(String packageName)`, since the `intent` will find a match through the `componentName` set by `Intent.setClassName(Context packageContext,String className)` or `Intent.setComponent(ComponentName component)`, you can find a match even you set a wrong packageName to the `Intent.setPackage(String packageName)`.

Comment: I wonder this myself...  Or the `.setAction(String);` may include the package name as well...  SOMETIMES it seems like all the necessary info is there and this extra step should only be needed when the defaults are not completely and explicitly obvious to every observer over a certain age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setClassName()` Targets an **exact** package name and **exact** component you want to run.
e.g. if you want to use the Gmail app to send an email using this to run the exact Activity(Component) you want to run.

`setPackage()` targets an **exact** application and offers you **all** components that can handle your intent.

If you **don't** fill these two it targets all apps and components which is not ideal in some cases e.g. you want to target only WhatApp to share content. If there is a case that you want to share that content on any social media app just ignore these two and stick with `action`, `data`, and ... fields.